# Dell Dimension l866r

Tags: windows-xp, post, floppy

I'm using an old Dell Dimension l866R desktop w/a floppy drive detected error upon boot. There is a floppy drive in the case but it's not connected to power supply nor motherboard. None of the keys are allowing me to enter BIOS setup to disable floppy drive. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using another keyboard
2. If the new keyboard doesn't work, go from USB to PS2 (or vice versa)
3. If none of these work, your motherboard could have something wrong with it and the sockets for the keyboard could be bad.

I noticed that with the Dell Dimension l866R, it only accepts the DEL key to get into BIOS. Give that a shot and comment back to tell me if anything worked.

Good Luck-

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you, no need to find out the wheel twice :)

Clear the BIOS by doing this:Disconnect the power cable from the back of the computer. Open the side cover and carefully take out the cmos battery (looks like a silvery button). Keep it out for about 15 minutes. Reinstall and reboot. You will probably get a checksome error or some other message. If you do, enter BIOS and set time and date, save the new values and let the computer boot. Most desktops will boot into BIOS by clicking Delete or F2 keys immediately after switching on. There are computers in which other keys have to be used to enter BIOS (Setup). You can find the correct key when looking at the screen right after pressing the start button. If you don't, press the Pause/Break key immediately after startup to freeze the first screen. Now you should be able to see what keys tp press